# Facebook fql not showing the photos and albums query

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, photos

I am using php-sdk for showing facebook information of the user. I have successfully shown the user profile info but while fetching any album or photos I am getting the blank data to me. I read the photos requires access_token. 
Also if I put this query in the facebook graph api explorer it showing me the perfect result. So query is right may be my way of passing the url is wrong.

I am not getting the issue. 
Please help.
    ';
              $app_secret = '';
              $my_url = '';

```
          $config = array(
            'appId' => '<appid>',
            'secret' => '<appsecrete>',
           );

            $facebook = new Facebook($config);
            $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

            $code = $_REQUEST["code"];
            if($user_id) {
             //auth user
             if(empty($code)) {
                $dialog_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' 
                    . $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) ;
                    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
              }

              //get user access_token
              $token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='
                . $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) 
                . '&client_secret=' . $app_secret 
                . '&code=' . $code;
              $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

             $fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.'fql?q=SELECT+pid,src_small+FROM+photo+WHERE+aid+IN+(SELECT+aid+FROM+album+WHERE+owner=+me())&'.$access_token;
             $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
             $fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);


          //display results of fql query
          echo '<pre>';
          print_r("query results:");
          print_r($fql_query_obj);
          echo '</pre>';
```

}
?>

Comment: I don’t see you asking for permissions anywhere in your code …?

Comment: permissions means to say to make your facebook photos public.. thats the few requisites that facebook has mentioned to fetch the photos. I am not getting why my result showing empty array,

Comment: That’s not enough, please see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/

Comment: Is there issue of user permission? Please tell me how to set in my code. I have taken this code from facebook developer api.

Comment: Did you read the page I just linked? It clearly states what permission you need for accessing the data you want to get. And for how to get permissions, please read the authentication documentation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One parameter needs to be add for $dialog_url variable which is 'scope' which defines  permissions to be given for application

```
$dialog_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id='.$app_id.'&redirect_uri='.urlencode($my_url).'&scope=user_photos';
                    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
```

for reference,

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

Thanks

Shreyas